# Get (static) offset from fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-position, offset, sticky

I have a "sticky" element with a fixed position. After the client resized his screen or the DOM has changed; I need to redefine the static (relative) position.

When the element has a fixed position (it sticks), I simply change the element's position to relative, get it's offset and reset the position:

```
if (self.isStick) {
    elemOffset = $element.css('position', 'relative').offset();
    $element.css('position', 'fixed');
} else {
    elemOffset = $element.offset();
}
```

This works, but It feels kind of hacky. I'm wondering if there is an alternative - with better performance. Any ideas?

Comment: `elemOffset = self.isStick ? $element.clone().css('position', 'relative').offset() : $element.offset();`

Answer (score 2):

Here is example using JQuery `.clone()` to copy the element. get element offset in one line

```
elemOffset = self.isStick ? $element.clone().css('position', 'relative').offset() : $element.offset();
```

Comment: That's a nice oneliner, but I'm pretty sure `.clone()` makes a deep copy of the elements and it's children. I think this performs worse then the given code. Correct me if i'm wrong tho.

Comment: You're taking about memory leaks